# How to change the name of file while exporting data to Excel?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

How do I change the name of file while exporting data to Excel?

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <button type="button"id="btnExport">Export to csv!</button>
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
<script>
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";

    window.open(result);

    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

When I click the export button I am getting as download.xls. Is it possible to set the file name  as data.xls? Can any one explain me where I need to configure that?

Comment: hai I had checked with the response.addheader but no use.Is there any alternative to change the name of the file

Comment: when I add the response.Addheader it was showing an error like undefined identifier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is an example which demonstrates Export HTML Table to Excel With Custom File Name: http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/javascript-export-html-table-to-excel-with-custom-file-name/

Answer (score 6):

Not only for excel, in addition, for many kind of format can useable.

```
 var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(htmlTable));
            element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
            document.body.removeChild(element);
```

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and since the new format (maybe not supported by every browser) `<a download=""></a>` the following worked fine for me. This use directly HTML/Javascript without the PHP server part, because using a submit form is too heavy for big data tables.

- changing `<button>` to `<a>`
- no more `window.open()`
- using the basic `<a>` behavior (so, no more `e.preventDefault()`) but changing `href` to `data:blabla` and adding `download="filename"` :

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <a href="#" id="btnExport" >Export to csv!</a>
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
        var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";
        this.href = result;
        this.download = "my-custom-filename.xls";
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works great, but for some reason changing `button` to `a` caused Windows to block the file (https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking).
Any idea how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with client-side JavaScript, you need to set the response header...

.NET

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=filename.xls")
```

Or PHP

```
$filename = 'somehting.xls';

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/11/ I placed the code but i am getting error can you please update in this fiddle

Comment: yes I tried with the response.Add header when i add it the button export is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=C:\YOURFILENAME.xls;"
```

Comment: While this answers the question, an explanation helps everyone understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
//getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
a.href = data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
//setting the file name
a.download = 'SupervisorReport.xls';
//triggering the function
a.click();
//just in case, prevent default behaviour
e.preventDefault();
return (a);
```